# How to embed a Video on Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, iframe, youtube

[SOLVED]I tried to embed a video in my Laravel project but all I'm getting is

> "www.youtube.com refused to connect."

the following is the html in my blade file.

```
<section id="intro_video">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="video_text">
            <h3>
                Section Title
            </h3>
            <p>
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="video">
            <iframe src="{{ url('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Peo-ivmupE') }}" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to show the video and users can click play to watch the video.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the source Url format from

```
<iframe src="{{ url('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Peo-ivmupE') }}" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to

```
<iframe src="{{ url('https://www.youtube.com/embed/5Peo-ivmupE') }}" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: hey thanks brother, ti works. i didn't know i had to put embed in it.

Answer (score 2):

The video url and the embedding url is different for youtube . You need to put the embedding code in this line of  code . To get the embedded code go to video do right click and see for copy embedded link

```
<iframe src="{{ url('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Peo-ivmupE') }}" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to

```
<iframe src="{{ url('https://www.youtube.com/embed/5Peo-ivmupE') }}" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I'm hoping this reply will help any future Google searchers as this question ranks pretty highly.

The [laravel-embed package](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-embed) can help by giving you the ability to embed a YouTube video (and others) using a blade component:

```html
<x-embed url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0" />
```

You simply pass the public URL of the video into the url attribute and the package will handle the rest.

Additionally there are validation rules for all the services supported by the package (it's not just YouTube) and it's responsive out of the box.

Comment: how to implement height width?